# containers can communicate with ports? ECS on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am moving my project from `ECS` on `fargate` to `ECS` on `EC2`

Now I have some troubles containers comunication.

```
f91bc9ec2092   678100221111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ol-dev-django:latest   "./entrypoint.fargat…"   11 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds              0.0.0.0:8011->8011/tcp, :::8011->8011/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   ecs-oldevecsTaskDefinition4BE5F675-24-ol-django-container-bef283fff2ff8d876f00
654e3b4370f6   678100221111.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/ol-dev-nginx:latest    "/docker-entrypoint.…"   11 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds              0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp                                                      ecs-oldevecsTaskDefinition4BE5F675-24-ol-nginx-container-d0bda396a09d84e6d601
```

From EC2 Node, I can see two containers are working.

then I login the container with EC2 node.

```
$docker exec -it 654e3b4370f6 /bin/bash` #login nginx container.
```

then in the container shell.

```
root@654e3b4370f6:/#curl localhost:8011` #connect to django container
```

However it says `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8011: Connection refused`

WHy this happens ?

When I am using Fargate, containers can contact each other with this methods.

I can not use port on ECS on EC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Fargate only supports the `awsvpc` Network mode for ECS tasks. In `awsvpc` Network mode containers can communicate with each other over `localhost`.

EC2 supports [several network modes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) for ECS tasks, and default to `bridge` network mode. If you want your containers to be able to communicate with each other over `localhost` and otherwise behave the same that they did when they were running on Fargate, then you need to configure your ECS deployed tasks to use `awsvpc` Network mode.

Comment: Thank you!!, I understood the reason why it doesn't connect. I am not sure what is  the advantage of `bridge `mode and why default is `bridge` mode though, I will use the `awsvpc` instead.

Comment: Bridge mode is just the standard network mode Docker normally uses. I wouldn't say there is an "advantage" to it, it's just the default. Bridge mode isn't available on Fargate because of the serverless nature of Fargate, so they had to default it to something else there.